# pandas to json with key

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I would like to create a json dict with key.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ABCAB'),
                   'b':[4,5,4,5,10],
                   'c':[7,8,9,5,10]})

df.set_index('a').to_json(orient='records')
print(d)
```

This will create a json dict looking like this: `[{"b":4,"c":7},{"b":5,"c":8},{"b":4,"c":9},{"b":5,"c":5},{"b":10,"c":10}]`

However, I am struggling to get this the way I want, I would preferably have a json dict that has key something like this: `["A":[{"b":4,"c":7}, {"b":5,"c":5}],"B": [{"b":5,"c":8},{"b":10,"c":10}], "C": [{"b":4,"c":9}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and lambda function with specify columns names, last call [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
d = df.groupby('a')['b','c'].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_json()
print(d)
{"A":[{"b":4,"c":7},{"b":5,"c":5}],
 "B":[{"b":5,"c":8},{"b":10,"c":10}],
 "C":[{"b":4,"c":9}]}
```

More dynamic solution is get columns names by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['a'])
d = df.groupby('a')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_json()
```